# How to add image into header in HTML/CSS Shopify?

Tags: html, css, header, shopify, e-commerce

I a trying to add image1 to my header on shopify. Would I need to overlap the header or add image1 to the header as one whole header?

I already have a logo and already uploaded the image to the Assets folder. What would I do next?

[my website header- green box is header space and red box is where i want the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLS4I.png)

The header.liquid code:

```
    <style>
  {%- assign logo_width = 695 -%}
  {%- assign logo_max_width = section.settings.logo_max_width | times: 1 -%}
  {% if logo_max_width < logo_width %}
    {%- assign logo_width = logo_max_width -%}
  {% endif %}
  .logo__image-wrapper {
    max-width: {{ logo_width }}px;
  }
  /*================= If logo is above navigation ================== */
  {% if section.settings.nav_below_logo %}
    .site-nav {
      {% if section.settings.show_header_lines %}
        border-top: 1px solid {{ settings.color_borders }};
        border-bottom: 1px solid {{ settings.color_borders }};
      {% endif %}
      margin-top: 30px;
    }

    {% unless section.settings.left_aligned_logo %}
      .logo__image-wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
    {% endunless %}
  {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this link it might help you with your issue all you need to do is to go to your header.liquid and add an image tag and set the source to what you like it to be

> https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Add-custom-image-in-header-space/td-p/336447

hope this solution helps you with your problem